# Why isn't my Node script exiting? (utilising Monk)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I'm writing a library to abstract my data layer (it's going to use a mix of Mongo and Memcached). I've been testing Monk and can't figure out why the below script isn't finishing:

```
mongo = require("monk")("mongodb://#{options.mongodb.username}:#{options.mongodb.password}@#{options.mongodb.hostname}:#{options.mongodb.port}/#{options.mongodb.database}")
users = mongo.get("users")
find = users.findById 12345
find.complete (err, doc) ->
  console.dir doc
  console.dir err
```

It's returning the document to the log, `{ _id: 12345, foo: "bar" }`, successfully but not completing when run using `node test.js`. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the script stays alive is because the connection to MongoDB is still open. If you call `mongo.close();` that should close the connection and provided you have nothing else keeping the event loop alive (e.g. network connections, timers, etc), then your script should terminate.

Comment: That's fixed it, thanks. I did look into closing the connection but the method `close()` isn't stated anywhere in the [Monk docs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/monk).

Comment: Yeah it's unfortunate, maybe submit a pull request to add it?